Solving for Hamming Weight Inequality in $\mathbb{F}_2^n$
Given random value vectors $X_i \in \mathbb{F}_2^n$, for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, m$, and a target range $[a, b]$, the objective is to efficiently find all solutions to the inequality $a \leq w_H\left(\sum_{i \in S} X_i\right) \leq b$, where $w_H$ denotes the Hamming weight of the vector and $S$ represents a solution set.
Here are the approaches that I can find out:

This problem can be formulated as an integer linear programming (ILP) problem.
Potentially, after computing a particular scenario, the relationship between the obtained Hamming weight and the target range can be leveraged to reduce the computation of adjacent scenarios, thereby reducing the number of exhaustive searches (i.e., in cases where the target is significantly distant, adjacent scenarios are also likely far from the target).
Using Gray code for exhaustive enumeration can help reduce redundant calculations.

